# Organize and increase work area in size

Tags: work, wood

I do electronics work in my apartment.

This is my current setup in my bedroom.

I have lumber scraps available and I enjoy making items, but would consider something else pre-made if it is cheap or free.

I looked at an armoir, but it is too big.

I want to use the existing table or make modifications to it, to have a work area to do my soldering and other projects. I had made a small table that stood about 11 inches higher that the table as shown in the photo to minimize bending over. (Neck pain)

But that table left about 14 inches of space behind it.

Which required having to reach around to use that space.

*Could someone help me with ideas on how to use that space effectively?*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You live in the USA, I would look on craigslist for a used armoire or TV cabinet of the right size.  If you are on a budget, check the free section daily.  Even if not free they can often be found cheap.

When you get it home, build a shelf that folds out and uses the doors for support that is your "work" table. You will proabably also want to add lighting inside the cabinet.  When it is closed it will look nice.  When it is open you will have more space.  Lots of room for hanging stuff on the inside, and drawers or shelves for putting your tools.

Comment: When I see TV cabinet, I think of those old ones that analog tvs came in. (Lifting those TV probably hurt my back.) Are you saying to look for a cabinet with doors and build a table work area on top of it? I would also like an area for storing my parts drawers. They take up about 20 x 20 inches.

Comment: @fixit7 before wide flat screens became "the thing" there were cabinets like armoires but for TVs [here is one](https://www.ballarddesigns.com/bd/224886?SourceCode=BDG006&intlShippingCtx=US%7CUSD&CAWELAID=120245430000427967&CAGPSPN=pla&CAAGID=43841479419&CATCI=pla-293946777986&kclid=8666aa18-23b6-4f29-8fd8-fadb5474c86e&catargetid=120245430000545147&cadevice=c&gclid=Cj0KCQjwjMfoBRDDARIsAMUjNZqi0IqviCqdWzyPYFsC4qIAyEy9lTGYJDOln-45wVwlPnRMECcsLyQaAtKAEALw_wcB) many don't fit modern TVs and are available for cheap

Comment: Ok. I found one for $99 at Amazon. At Ebay, I saw some for pickup only. I could shop flea markets or garage sales, but that is a lot of work. I am a fair hand with making wooded boxs and mounting doors. Not a problem installing a light either.

Comment: @fixit7 [this one](https://galveston.craigslist.org/fuo/d/galveston-beautiful-painted-tv-bureau/6913276487.html) is free and 30 miles from you.

Comment: @fixit7 if my answer solves your problem you can mark it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I have edited my original post. This may take a while, but should be worth the effort. @James Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep workbenches along walls and in the center of a room if that leaves enough space - it is often very useful to have multiple surfaces.

A like a tool shelf mounted the wall at my workbenches that are against walls, it is nice to set a tool down close by, and out of the way of the workspace.

Keep tool storage close, but out of the way. Closer to the work space by frequency of use if possible. A sturdy bench gives you shelving underneath.

Boxes and totes with lids and labels can be stored under work benches easily, and are easy to access and retrieve. I like to keep tools and materials that are commonly used together in smaller "kits" - so if I am going to do a specific type of work, I need to only get out one or two kits, and then maybe a few other tools.

Peg boards can be very useful and good space saves too.

Answer (score -1):

Consider taking everything you have now and everything you are using and **raising the level** to a working height most comfortable for you. In effect, it will be your standing desk.

Rather than a small unstable work table on top of a normal desktop height (28-38 inches/70-95cm), lift your main table surface to give you enough room to work on your biggest projects. That'll also free some space underneath for storage that you can reach more conveniently.

For added comfort, you could get a tall stool so you don't have to stand for long; but, you could take a load off occasionally.

No?

Okay, do the opposite and **lower yourself**. Sit on a low chair or stool so that your "relative" working height is higher and more comfortable. Wheels under your chair will help you move around, too.

Not good enough?

Okay, you can do both. A two-tier-main and smaller offset surface higher for close-up work - you can add under-shelf lighting for a versatile well-lit workshop.

Good luck with your new workshop!